# How to add HttpContextAccessor in Startup in C# net core api project

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

There are several ways to add HttpContextAccessor for dependency injection.

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Here is my understanding:

1. Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services. Register transient services with AddTransient.

In apps that process requests, transient services are disposed at the end of the request.

2. A scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request (connection). Register scoped services with AddScoped.
3. Singleton lifetime services are created either:

The first time they're requested.
By the developer, when providing an implementation instance directly to the container. This approach is rarely needed.

How do we explain the following?

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

I checked with Microsoft web site. It says

It adds a default implementation for the IHttpContextAccessor service.

Does that mean that we should not use AddSingleton, AddScoped, and AddTransient?

Comment: It's just an extension method to help you register a default implementation

Comment: [AddHttpContextAccessor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Http/Http/src/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27) is just a convenient helper method that calls `AddSingleton`.

Comment: @Steven Do you have a reference that AddHttpContextAccessor() is the same as AddSingleton?

Comment: @user3097695: I just did. Follow the link

Comment: @Steven Can you put your as an answer?